# FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ea', but it was: a custom Na object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await

i was following along the guidelines that firebase provides and i ran into this error.

```
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      if (user) {
        const collRef = getDocs(db, "users", user?.id);
        const orderedRef = query(collRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
        const docSnap = await onSnapshot(orderedRef);
        setOrders(docSnap);
        orders.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }));
      } else {
        setOrders([]);
      }
    };
    getData();
  }, [user]);
```

and i get this

> Orders.jsx:36 Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Expected type 'Ea', but it was: a custom Na object

--UPDATE--

I just wanted to point out that I'm new to firebase and I was following a video guide that is from a couple years ago and they weren't using the v9 modular style.

From their video their code goes as follows:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(user) {
        db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection('orders')
        .orderBy('created', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => (
            setOrders(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data()
            })))
        ))
    } else {
        setOrders([])
    }

  }, [user])
```

I am trying to emulate this function using the v9 modular style but am running into some issues.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? Are you looking for a specific user? or trying to query all the users?

Comment: @Christian Paul Andaya I am trying to order the "orders" collection in descending order using the 'created' id and display them in my orders component.

Comment: To order the  "orders" collection, you would need to assign that in the collRef var. As is, you're trying to order the "users" collection `const collRef = getDocs(db, "users"`. There are other issues as well but that's the main one.

Comment: @Jay I'm sorry, yes i originally had the line as ```const collRef = getDocs(db,"users","user?.id","orders");``` .

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a query there is no need to use the getDocs. You may check this documentation for [examples](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#simple_queries).

Sample Code:

```
    const collRef = collection(db,"users","user?.id","orders")
    const orderedRef = query(colRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
    onSnapshot(orderedRef, (querySnapshot) => {
        setOrders(
            querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data(),
            }))
        );
    });
```